# Kendo - Material theme does not match demo

Tags: css, kendo-ui

For example, the editor demo (http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/editor/index) displays the bold icon as black when hovering.

[image]

However, outside of the demo, the bold icon displays as white using the material theme. Please see http://dojo.telerik.com/OHiZa for the code. This white font is hard to read. 
[image]

How can I have the material theme have the same style as the demo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I using the following common style:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
```

I should have used:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css">
```

Comment: Although this Kendo blog post indicates you should not include `kendo.common-material.min.css`. It doesn't say what the purpose of `kendo.common-THEME.min.css` is.

Comment: this solved it for me. I was adding the kendo.common when I should have been adding kendo.common.material.core.css

Comment: @StuartHallows, please refer to [LESS-Based Themes](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/styles-and-layout/appearance-styling) which explains the purpose of `kendo.common-THEME.min.css` files.